# Electricity off while shrinking database, how can I recover my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, recovery

While i execute shrink database, the electricity has been gone down, I can't access my database now, it is (In Recovery), how can i recover it??
Note: it is a very huge database: 25 GB.

**EDIT:**

My question on serverfault.com:
https://serverfault.com/questions/395067/electricity-gone-off-while-shrinking-database-how-can-i-recover-my-database

Comment: Why off-topic?? this is a very possible case!

Comment: I have it and i searched for it, and no answer!

Comment: Take a look at http://serverfault.com maybe they can help you. (I've not flaged your question)

Comment: Please, comment here, why off-topic???

Comment: BTW, you should never be shrinking a database....

Comment: Why off-topic? I'd have thought that obvious: there is no programming question.

Comment: Recovering database when electricity gone off is aver important question, and i have this case, and i have searched hardly, but i didn't find any answer!, please don't flag or -1 this question!

Comment: Important or not: this is the wrong forum. Try http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, I see, I will ask it on server fault, but please, let it here and i will link my new question there, (To let SQL server developer share their experience)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is off-topic here. You can create your question on one of the proposed sites if there isn't already a similar one. We know this is no good feeling, but there you can get better chances of solving your problem. (now I've flaged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No backup, no chance of recovery. Note that the back up doesn't need to be recent, as long as you have every log file since the last backup which you can play back to reach the point in time of the failure.
2. I doubt you have 25Gb of data you actually need for production. Consider running a separate server for reporting purposes (aka data warehousing) by splitting your data up into:

   - "data you need to process transactions" (eg the last 30 days of transactions)
   - "data for reporting" (everything else)

Data warehousing makes your production system smaller and therefore easier to manage changes and backups, and faster.

Try asking your question on  http://dba.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ehe Ehe Ehe, i have been ******, I think you are right, but it is a big lesson.

Comment: It become after a while of time, i didn't do anything, it recovered automatically!!!!

Comment: Both answers seem to have missed the fact that the database was in restart recovery. The shrink operation is logged to the transaction log using the WAL protocol and this is intended to allow recovery from exactly this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This won't help you solve your problem, but it has to be said.

1) **BEFORE** Performing anything that will alter your database: **TAKE A BACKUP!**

2) There are few valid reasons for shrinking a database. If you find your self requiring this you probably have lots of tables with no clustered indexes, OR poorly choosen clustered indexes. If you really have to shrink, then **TAKE A BACKUP!** first

3) A database of size 25GB sounds like it contains important data, therefore it should be on a production server box. Production server boxes should have an Uninterruptible Power Suppy (UPS).

All that said, I strongly recommended heading over to Paul Randall's blog. He has many posts relating to recovery of SQL Server databases. e.g.

- [Disaster recovery 101: hack-attach a damaged database](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Disaster-recovery-101-hack-attach-a-damaged-database.aspx).
- [Using EMERGENCY mode to access a RECOVERY PENDING or SUSPECT database](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Search-Engine-QA-4-Using-EMERGENCY-mode-to-access-a-RECOVERY-PENDING-or-SUSPECT-database.aspx)

You might even consider hiring a professional in your region. Perhaps contact Microsoft.

Comment: Do you think Microsoft can recommend a professional? ;-)

Comment: I was trying to make a joke that they themselves are not. nm.